# UnitTest Python mock only one function multiple call

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using Mock (http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html), and came across a particular mock case that I cant figure out the solution.

I have a function with multiple calls to some_function that is being Mocked.

```
def function():
    some_function(1)
    some_function(2)
    some_function(3)
```

I only wanna mock the first and third call to some_function. The second call I wanna to be made to the real some_function.

I tried some alternatives with http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.mock_calls, but with no success.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock side effect only X number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081457/mock-side-effect-only-x-number-of-times)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems that the `wraps` argument could be what you want:

> *wraps*: Item for the mock object to wrap. If wraps is not None then calling the
> Mock will pass the call through to the wrapped object (returning the
> real result and ignoring return_value).

However, since you only want the second call to not be mocked, I would suggest the use of [`mock.side_effect`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.side_effect).

> If side_effect is an iterable then each call to the mock will return
> the next value from the iterable.

If you want to return a different value for each call, it's a perfect fit :

```
somefunction_mock.side_effect = [10, None, 10]
```

Only the first and third calls to `somefunction` will return 10.

However, if you do need to call the *real* function, but not the second time, you can also pass `side_effect` a callable, but I find it pretty ugly (there might be a smarter to do it):

```
 class CustomMock(object):

     calls = 0

     def some_function(self, arg):
         self.calls += 1
         if self.calls != 2:
             return my_real_function(arg)
         else:
             return DEFAULT

somefunction_mock.side_effect = CustomMock().some_function
```

Answer (score 6):

Even simpler than creating a `CustomMock` class :

```
def side_effect(*args, **kwargs):
    if side_effect.counter < 10:
        side_effect.counter += 1
        return my_real_function(arg) 
    else:
        return DEFAULT

side_effect.counter = 0
mocked_method.side_effect = side_effect
```

Comment: I've found that `my_real_function` needed to be aliased, as in `import my_real_function as someother_name` otherwise the `side_effect` function keeps being called in an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same situation today. After some hesitation I found a different way to work around it.

At first, I have a function looks like this:

```py
def reboot_and_balabala(args):
    os.system('do some prepare here')
    os.system('reboot')
    sys.exit(0)
```

I want the first call to os.system be invoked, otherwise the local file is not generated, and I cannot verify it.
But I really do not want the second call to os.system be invoked, lol.

At first, I have an unittest similar to:

```py
def test_reboot_and_balabala(self):
    with patch.object(os, 'system') as mock_system:
        # do some mock setup on mock_system, this is what I looked for
        # but I do not found any easy and clear solution
        with patch.object(sys, 'exit') as mock_exit:
            my_lib.reboot_and_balabala(...)
            # assert mock invoke args
            # check generated files
```

But finally, I realized, after adjusting the code, I have a more better code structure, and unittests, by following way:

```py
def reboot():
    os.system('reboot')
    sys.exit(0)

def reboot_and_balabala(args):
    os.system('do some prepare here')
    reboot()
```

And then we can test those code by:

```py
def test_reboot(self):
    with patch.object(os, 'system') as mock_system:
        with patch.object(sys, 'exit') as mock_exit:
            my_lib.reboot()
            mock_system.assert_called_once_with('reboot')
            mock_exit.assert_called_once_with(0)

def test_reboot_and_balabala(self):
    with patch.object(my_lib, 'reboot') as mock_reboot:
        my_lib.reboot_and_balabala(...)
        # check generated files here
        mock_reboot.assert_called_once()
```

This is not a direct answer to the question. But I think this is very inspiring.