# python UnitTest mock leverage side_effect to "mock" on multiple functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

code.py

```
def invoke_command():
    ...
    return {'invoke': 'block'}

def attach_volume():
    ...
    return {'path': dev_str}

def create_cloned_volume():
    create_volume() # calls invoke_command
    create_snapshot() # calls invoke_command
    ...
    attach_volume()
```

test.py

```
mock_invoke = None

def fake_invoke_command():
    return {'invoke': 'block'}

def fake_attach_volume():
    return {'path': dev_str}

def test_create_cloned_volume(self):
    self.mock_invoke.invoke_command = mock.Mock()
    self.mock_invoke.side_effect = self.fake_invoke_command
    self.mock_invoke.side_effect = self.fake_attach_command
    self.handle.create_cloned_volume()
```

Hello,
 In my code.py, there is `create_cloned_volume` which has calls to `create_volume, create_snapshot and attach_volume`. Now, `create_volume` and `create_snapshot` have calls to `invoke_command` which i need to mock. I am able to mock this successfully. But also, i need to mock call to `attach_volume` which is failing if i again give a side_effect to `fake_attach_volume`. I am not able to figure out how to mock the second call to some other function. Please note that there may be numerous calls to `invoke_command and attach_volume` inside `create_clone_volume`. I also read that
`If you want to return a different value for each call, it's a perfect fit :`

`somefunction_mock.side_effect = [10, None, 10]` from [UnitTest Python mock only one function multiple call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751467/unittest-python-mock-only-one-function-multiple-call)

I don't know if this can be used for my case.

Thanks,
prathamesh

Comment: Is this your full code? I don't see how you're using `self` outside of a class there. But yes, `side_effect` can be used to change one or more calls to a function / method.