# Mock multiple return value including original behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

In underlying logic actually in library I have some class. For testing some business logic based on that I need to keep original behavior for N time and finally get some `Exception`.

```
from unittest import mock

class A():
    def orig(self):
        return 5
```

Let's say `orig` method should fail after 2 successful calls.
I have managed something like that:

```
with mock.patch.object(A, 'orig', side_effect=[mock.Mock(wraps=A.orig)(A), mock.Mock(wraps=A.orig)(A), ValueError]):
    print(A.orig())
    print(A.orig())
    print(A.orig())
```

But that doesn't look like right approach due to some messing with passing arguments.
And it isn't reliable solution.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to call `orig()` *on `A`*, there is no instance. You'll need to create an instance first, then call the method on that. Personally, I'd not wrap the method at all, just provide `[5, 5, ValueError]` here.

Comment: That's is very simplified example. In library I have some network stuff so I can't just return smth by hand :(

Comment: In other words, if you are testing a unit of code that calls `A().orig()`, then `A().orig()` is *outside the scope of the unit test* and should be mocked wholesale. You are not testing the behaviour of `A().orig()` here, you are testing how *other code* uses the return value and then handles the exception.

Comment: Network stuff is **certainly** out of scope for a unit test.

Comment: So it should be mocked *wholesale* right?

Comment: Exactly. You should have a separate test for `A().orig()` really, and that test should mock out the network stuff.