# MagicMock's reset_mock not properly resetting sub-mock's side_effect

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest.mock, magicmock

I have a long-lived patch on a class, whose made instance undergoes multiple batches of assertions.  Please see the below code snippet for the scenario.

It exposes (what I think is annoying) behavior in `MagicMock.reset_mock` where it seemingly creates a new `MagicMock` inside a sub-`MagicMock`:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

mock_cls = MagicMock()
mock_cls.return_value.method.side_effect = [5]
instance = mock_cls()

# Batch 1 of usage: uses side_effect
assert instance.method() == 5

mock_cls.reset_mock(return_value=True, side_effect=True)
# After this, mock_cls.return_value.method has a new id

# Batch 2 of usage: uses return_value
instance.return_value.method.return_value = 6
assert instance.method() == 6  # StopIteration
```

When run with Python 3.10.2, it raises a `StopIteration`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/code/play/quick_play.py", line 9, in <module>
    assert instance.method() == 6
  File "/path/to/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1104, in __call__
    return self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1108, in _mock_call
    return self._execute_mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1165, in _execute_mock_call
    result = next(effect)
StopIteration
```

Is it possible to use `reset_mock` without creating new `MagicMock`?

Alternately, how can I manually reset the `side_effect` so the snippet runs?

---

**Aside**

What is the `visited=None` argument for in `reset_mock`'s signature?  It's undocumented in the [3.10 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/unittest.mock.html), and here

```py
def reset_mock(self,  visited=None,*, return_value=False, side_effect=False):
```

Comment: From the docs: *"Note that reset_mock() doesn’t clear the return value, side_effect or any child attributes..."*

Comment: @KlausD. hence the kwargs passed to `reset_mock`, read the doc's next few sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes in life, you answer your own question.

**Alternate to `reset_mock`**

From the `side_effect` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect)

> If the function returns `DEFAULT` then the mock will return its normal value (from the `return_value`).

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, DEFAULT

mock_cls = MagicMock()
mock_cls.return_value.method.side_effect = [5]
instance = mock_cls()
instance.method()

# Works, aligns with docs
mock_cls.return_value.method.side_effect = lambda: DEFAULT
instance.method()  # <MagicMock name='mock().method()' ...>

# Alternately, this works too
mock_cls.return_value.method.side_effect = None
instance.method()  # <MagicMock name='mock().method()' ...>
```

You can also find this [used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56191297/11163122) and [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32090685/11163122).

---

**Fixing My Snippet**

There are two learnings here:

- Ditching `reset_mock` in favor of setting `side_effect = None`
- `return_value` for the 2nd batch was used incorrectly
- Alternately, I could've called `reset_mock` on the made `instance`

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

mock_cls = MagicMock()
mock_cls.return_value.method.side_effect = [5]
instance = mock_cls()

# Batch 1 of usage: uses side_effect
assert instance.method() == 5

mock_cls.return_value.method.side_effect = None
# instance.reset_mock(side_effect=True)  # Also works

# Batch 2 of usage: uses return_value
instance.method.return_value = 6  # Correct
# instance.return_value.method.return_value = 6  # Original incorrect
assert instance.method() == 6
```

Future readers: stay hungry, stay foolish.